# Remove jQuery added on doc ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a script that adds tinymce to a textarea on page ready. How do I remove this code using jquery, so this piece of code doesn't do any changes to the page? (I can't modify this from the core files) I need to remove the code that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   jQuery('#join_form [name="DescriptionMe[0]"]').tinymce({

       plugins: 'autolink,autosave,lists,inlinepopups,paste,fullscreen',
       width: '100%',
       height: '150',
       theme: 'advanced',
       theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline,removeformat,|,bullist,numlist,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,blockquote,|,link,unlink,image',
       theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
       theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
       theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
       theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left',
       theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'none',

       document_base_url: 'http://website.com/demo/d7s/',
       remove_script_host: false,
       relative_urls: false,
       script_url: 'http://website.com/demo/d7s/plugins/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php',
       skin: 'default',
       language: 'en',
       content_css: 'http://website.com/demo/d7s/templates/base/css/editor.css',
       gecko_spellcheck: true,
       entity_encoding: 'raw',
       verify_html: false
   });

 });

 $(document).ready(function () {

         jQuery('#join_form [name="DescriptionMe[1]"]').tinymce({

               plugins: 'autolink,autosave,lists,inlinepopups,paste,fullscreen',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '150',
                        theme: 'advanced',
                        theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline,removeformat,|,bullist,numlist,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,blockquote,|,link,unlink,image',
                        theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
                        theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left',
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: 'none',

                        document_base_url: 'http:/ / website.com / demo / d7s / ',
                        remove_script_host: false,
                        relative_urls: false,
                        script_url: '
   http: //website.com/demo/d7s/plugins/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.php',
   skin: 'default',
   language: 'en',
   content_css: 'http://website.com/d7s/templates/base/css/editor.css',
   gecko_spellcheck: true,
   entity_encoding: 'raw',
   verify_html: false
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the code from javascript I think, but what you could do is change the name of the textarea that is converted into a tinyMCE box

Something like:

```
jQuery('#join_form [name="DescriptionMe[0]"]').attr('name', 'somethingelse');
```

Then when the tinyMCE command runs it can't find the textarea. If you need the textarea server-side afterwards you can rename the element back to what it was.

```
jQuery('#join_form [name="somethingelse"]').attr('name', 'DescriptionMe[0]');
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you just make your object null like

```
jQuery('#join_form [name="DescriptionMe[0]"]').tinymce=null;
```

Just try it out